# how i can override the observer of other modules in magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer, price

> how i can  override observer of other module(custom module)
>
> to my another custom modules in magento 2
>
> is it possible ???

Does anyone have an idea?

ex :

*custom module 1:*

the observer for catalog price change

*custom module 2:*

**i want the price of changed by observer in custom module1.**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can using preference

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Vendor1\ModuelName1\Observer\FileName1" type="Vendor2\ModuelName2\Observer\FileName2" />
</config>
```

Just copy the existing observer from **FileName1.php** to 
**FileName2.php** and do alter the namespace and all. and I hope it works.

> Despite executing first observer it will execute second observer.

Comment: how to get the product price changed by the observer in another module

Comment: No that's not possible, guess you're setting custom price in quote so you can get quote again and can change it accordingly. that's possible

Comment: so i need to add discount logic agin in module 2 observer

Answer (score 0):

> Using `Preference` it's is possible

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Vendor\module1\file\location" type="\Vendor\module2\file\location" /> 
</config>
```

Comment: i have another doubt

Comment: i have  changed the  price of product using  custom  module1(for some discount for customer)

Comment: after  another module 2.  i will  get the price but it's  getting Product orignal price not  getting  discount price

Comment: how  i can get that discount price  in custom module 2??

Comment: Hi Rk Rathod, can you pls help me with https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/336522/57334

Answer (score 0):

To override an observer, I think better way is to use events.xml rather than using preference.

Suppose you have `events.xml` in `ModuleA`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="some_event">
        <observer name="myObserverName" instance="MyCompany\ModuleA\Observer\MyObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now if you want to override the observer `MyCompany\ModuleA\Observer\MyObserver`, then create events.xml in your custom module as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="some_event">
            <observer name="myObserverName" instance="MyCompany\CustomModule\Observer\MyObserver" />
        </event>
    </config>
```

And in your custom module's(`MyCompany_CustomModule`) `module.xml` add `sequence` of `MyCompany_ModuleA`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyCompany_CustomModule">
        <sequence>
            <module name="MyCompany_ModuleA" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Also, **Magento recommends to use plugins for data modification. Observers should not be used for data modifications**.

Comment: some confusions in name of mycomapany_module and custom module 

could you plz explain clear ly

Comment: @prabhakaran7 MyCompany_ModuleA is the module name that you want to override and MyCompany_CustomModule is the module name that you are using to override the MyCompany_ModuleA