# Magento 2.4: How to create Observer for "after save" event in custom module

Tags: event-observer, magento2.4.1, google-api

I am using the custom module, in the backend, there are two fields, **Field 1** manually entered **Field 2** get the values based on **Field 1**. Here I want to get the **Field 1** value in Observer **after click save**, after getting that **Field 1** then I need to pass that value to

https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/123456789/locations?filter=storeCode=SAN)   // SAN is my **Field 1** value

The API returns the Location Id which I want to be saved to **Field 2**

Answer (score 0):

So you could do this in the `beforeSave` event of the model. If this is all in a custom module, all you have to do is define in your model the `beforeSave` method (making sure to call the `parent::beforeSave()`) and then add your code to populate Field 2 based on the input from Field 1.

If you wanted to do this in the validation stage, you could create a custom validator and add it to your model's validation rules stack. You could query for the information you need while also validating that you get a result and prevent saving of invalid or incomplete data.

See https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/d4f3adfeeb813ddbe7bfc76db731b69018e8f8ec/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/AbstractModel.php#L696